# Simple table echo in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm building this function but I'm not getting the desired output, it's been more than 5 hours I'm still on this.

I have this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess");
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach( $checked1 as $key => $value){
   echo "<th> $value </th>";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
         echo "<tr>" . $row[$value] . "</tr>"; 
      }
   }
}
echo "</table>";
```

What I need is to print the first `$value` as the heads of the table, then the `$row[value]` as the rows, but I get to print the headings, then the rest just prints in a single line, all of it.

Comment: Oh no no, this is another question..

Comment: if you stop editing the code for a moment, and taking a pen and paper to evaluate the data you have and what you want to get out of it, you'll get it in no time

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD) (see the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/a4i0f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understand better now.  Your issue is that you're not printing the tags and values in the right order.  Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess");
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<thead><tr>"
foreach( $checked1 as $key => $value){
   echo "<th> $value </th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
        echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>"; 
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Heh, i tried it and it gives me some other output..
What i need to do is just, past the first $values like headings and the other rows to come like that, rows...

Comment: the problem is that with foreach it creates a new row and td.. what i need is to create only a row for all the td . $row[$value] . printed..

Answer (score 1):

in order to properly debug your problem, please remember how a table usually looks:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

so, look at what your code is outputting by wrapping the output in some `<pre>` tags. and you'll see what you're missing.

also, there are a lot of tutorials on the topic of outputting mysql tables as html -- maybe you can just steal one from somewhere.

```
http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/display-results-from-query-in-html-table-4095.html
or http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__display_table_as_html.xml
```

also also, if you really wanna nerd out with me for a second, if you take a look at a popular design pattern called the [factory pattern](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-php-factory-pattern/), you really could build a great table class out of it.